# proficient with or proficient in?

Tags: word-usage, phrases

Technically proficient with Microsoft Office Suite?
Or
Technically proficient in Microsoft Office Suite?

Please help me to understand if the sentence is correct?

Thank You!

Comment: In the example you have given I certainly much prefer "in". However, being British, I may be in a minority here. I don't think I would use "with", but if the proficiency related to something that was a casual skill rather than a more professional competence, I might use "at". E.G. "Jane had become proficient at making omelettes the French way".  However bear in mind that when it comes to prepositions, the Atlantic ocean gets to be very wide.